# c# open cmd and continue - nodeJS Dashboard update

Tags: c#, node.js, mongodb, visual-studio-2012, cmd

I am developing a app for start javascript/nodeJS files thrugh
a simple user interface that loads the JS script.
[nodeJS Dashboard](https://github.com/aCo0o/nodeJS_Dashboard)

A Tool that i want to add is a "Start mongoDB" - that starts a mongod instance.

We start our DB fist with (mongod), then our server.

**The Problem:**

I am able to open just ONE instance of CMD thru the c# Form..

Any suggestions?

**PS. The mongod instance in the image is a manually started one**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What about using:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("path"); //insert path here to mongodb
```

You can use it to open more than 1 process...

Comment: Bless you ... 
but i found out that WaitForExit(); was blocking my form